# What is the sword style in 大巧不工剑讲究的就是一个不工，意念要厚重，剑式要雄强圆厚...?

Tags: translation

> 大巧不工剑讲究的就是一个不工，意念要厚重，剑式要雄强圆厚，气势要庄严雄浑，你看看你使出的剑式，太过松散，转折太过刚硬，致使出剑无力，剑式笼罩的范围太小……”

I’m not learning Chinese, I just enjoy doing machine translations to read and translate, but Google and the dictionary can only take me so far. What is the sword style here called? Whats the translation of this passage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 大巧不工 is from 《重剑无锋，大巧不工》

1. 重 heavy
2. 剑 sword
3. 无 no
4. 锋 sharp edge
5. 大 big
6. 巧 delicate
7. 不 no
8. 工 work

《重剑无锋，大巧不工》
**Epee with no sharp edge, delicate work**

*The true power is not from the weapon, is from the one who uses it.*

**What is the sword style here called?**

Sword style means the the moves of the swordsman

**Whats the translation of this passage???**

大巧不工剑 is the name of the sword moves i assume.

讲究的就是一个不工 is all about natural (不工 not artificial)

意念要厚重 thoughts must be strong

剑式要雄强圆厚 moves must be strong and round and thick (round and thick here means the moves must be flexible and comprehensive)

气势要庄严雄浑 momentum must be 庄严 Solemn and serious 雄浑(雄壮浩瀚: expansive)

你看看你使出的剑式，太过松散 look at your move, too loose

转折太过刚硬 moves transition too solid (not flexible)

致使出剑无力 causing your attack powerless

剑式笼罩的范围太小 area covered by your moves is too small

Answer (score 1):

Question :- "What is the sword style here....?

As someone who loves reading Chinese martial arts novels, (武侠小说), and have practiced Chinese martial arts in my younger days, I can relate to the passage in question, and can opine that the passage on the face of it does not depict any particular "style" of swordplay, like 太極, 武當，八卦, 峨眉，少林， etc, but just some general pointers on wielding the Chinese long sword, 剑, effectively。

However having said that, and from the passage, 剑式要雄强圆厚....转折太过刚硬, which appears to be a contradiction in terms is actually an allusion to the Yin Yang, 阴阳 philosophy of an intrinsic interplay of seemingly opposing yet complementary forces, I would opine that the "Style" is more towards 太極, 武當, probably more of the latter.

But the repertoire of Chinese sword styles is so numerous and broad that even experts would argue over them due to its secretive nature and convoluted history.